# docker-compose can't find/run start.sh

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I'm working on a docker-compose setup for my django/react app for development purposes. I've got everything working with the Django Dockerfile, but with React I've been struggling with getting it to run my `start.sh`. It seems it can't find it.

Error:

```
ERROR: for node_server  Cannot start service node: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused "exec: \"/start.sh\": stat /start.sh: no such file or directory": unknown
compose.parallel.parallel_execute_iter: Failed: <Service: node>
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()

ERROR: for node  Cannot start service node: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused "exec: \"/start.sh\": stat /start.sh: no such file or directory": unknown
ERROR: compose.cli.main.main: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

node Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:11-alpine

RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code

ADD ./frontend .

RUN npm install

COPY ./docker_compose/node/development/start.sh /code/start.sh
RUN sed -i 's/\r//' start.sh \
    && chmod +x start.sh
```

Full docker-compose-dev.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:

  postgres:
    container_name: postgres_server
    image: postgres:11-alpine
    env_file: .env
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - local_postgres_data_dev:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - local_postgres_backup_dev:/backups

  node:
    container_name: node_server
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker_compose/node/development/Dockerfile
    command: /start.sh
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"

  django:
    container_name: django_server
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker_compose/django/development/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - node
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    env_file: .env
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    command: /start.sh

volumes:
  local_postgres_data_dev: {}
  local_postgres_backup_dev: {}
```

start.sh:

```
#!/bin/ash
npm start
```

Project structure:

```
.
├── api
├── financeApp
├── config
├── datadumps
├── docker-compose-dev.yml
├── docker-compose.yml
├── docker_compose
├── frontend (this is my react app)
├── manage.py
├── requirements
└── templates
```

**Edit**

If I change `command` in docker-compose to `command: ls` this is what is returned:

```
node_server | api
node_server | financeApp
node_server | config
node_server | datadumps
node_server | docker-compose-dev.yml
node_server | docker-compose.yml
node_server | docker_compose
node_server | frontend
node_server | manage.py
node_server | requirements
node_server | templates
```

So it looks like `start.sh` isn't even there?

Answer (score 0):

You want run `/start.sh` on your compose, you are searching by complete path, try with `/code/start.sh`.

Comment: If I change it to `command: /bin/ash /code/start.sh` I still get: `node_server | /bin/ash: can't open '/code/start.sh': No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0):

You try to execute /start.sh in root of filesystem but your workdir is /code
Change path or change workdir
Or try /code/start.sh

Comment: If I change it to `command: /bin/ash /code/start.sh` I still get: `node_server | /bin/ash: can't open '/code/start.sh': No such file or directory`

Comment: The `command: ls` from above appears to be from within `/code`. `command: pwd` returns `/code`

Answer (score 0):

Try below in your DockerFile. The problem is that your `start.sh` file is not getting copied under `code` directory. Because you are already in the `code` Directory and you are trying to move/copy `start.sh` under new `code` directory.

Either you should not use `/code/start.sh` after you make `code` as your current directory or you should make `code` your current directory after you copy all required files in that folder and then run `start.sh` only.

```
FROM node:11-alpine

RUN mkdir /code

ADD ./frontend .    

COPY ./docker_compose/node/development/start.sh /code/start.sh

# Make Code your working directory.
WORKDIR /code

RUN npm install

RUN sed -i 's/\r//' start.sh \
    && chmod +x start.sh
```

Best practice is that copy all your files first and then run commands on those files. `RUN npm install` should always be the last step after copying all your files to the directory and making that directory your working directory.

Comment: I still get the same error as above with this Dockerfile and `command: /start.sh`

Comment: Make sure that your `start.sh` file's host location path is correct. I tried on my local machine and it is working fine. I am not getting any error while building.

Comment: On my local host this is the location of `start.sh`: `<project_root>/docker_compose/node/development/start.sh`, but in my Dockerfile I'm copying `start.sh` to `/code/start.sh`. So is docker-compose trying to run `start.sh` from my local host or from `/code` in the container?

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if my project structure is what's causing this issue. Namely having my react code in the `./frontend` directory whereas `docker-compose-dev.yml` is in the project root. Or should this be feasible with my structure?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you have found solution for this but, i think this is because you are mounting volume on same path in docker-compose-dev.yml.

First Dockerfile will copy the start.sh file in /code 
but then docker-compose-dev.yml will mount volume on same path overwriting /code. Thus, removing previous copied start.sh script.

Try COPY start.sh in different path. You have to adjust your start.sh file.